# What design principle/pattern should I choose?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, vsto

I have developed a VSTO 4.0 add-in, designed for the integration of our business application into Microsoft Word. Code written in the making add-in, is a mini framework that I would like to re-use for a new add-in for Microsoft PowerPoint. The main problem is that the Word and PowerPoint interfaces (for example, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table and Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Table) do not have a common ancestor, but I need to create an general API for inserting, updating, tables and graphs, etc., which will be standardized to work with of Word and PowerPoint objects. What design principle/pattern should I choose? Example of class that I use is given below:

```
 using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

 public class ReportHolder
 {
     public ReportHolder(Word.Document document) { ... }

     public void AddTable(Word.Range range) { ... }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are unable to find a common interface at the level of the application hierarchy you require to implement a satisfactory generalization there are at least two and probably more options you can choose from.

The first option would be to implement a [**strategy pattern**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) and define your own interface for the strategy's.  Once you do this you can code to the definition of the strategy's interface and then within each strategy class code the type specific logic for word, excel, power-point etc.  Once you have all the strategy class in place you can implement a [**factory pattern**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) to gain the code reuse you are seeking.

The second option would be to use more generic type objects to the arguments of your functions such at interfaces and type object references. Once you do that you can leverage the reflection classes in the .net framework to do type checking on specific objects and then handle each specific case.

Lastly before looking at these alternatives or any others I would suggest really digging into the msdn documentation to understand the overall architecture of the office interoperability framework for .net to see if there are valid generalizations you can make and existing patterns that are in place for code reuse.  I also know that late binding is used extensively throughout the framework for this purpose and it may be a good place to start.  Here is some additional reference material.

[**Late Binding In Office Solutions**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/3xxe951d.aspx)

[**Writing Code In Office Solutions**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb608596.aspx)

Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you, one of my versions was an version with System.Object in signatures, but it did not suit me because of my weak typing.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are looking for the [Adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) pattern.

One other approach, might be for your framework to handle what it does, in an abstract and common way, through your own set of classes. And then have two different strategies for rendering the content (two separate renderers, one for Word and one for Powerpoint).

Comment: Thank you, I really want to make two separate implementations for Word and PowerPoint, but I need a basic abstraction layer, which would unite them.